# Return Boolean in Has Type Function

Tags: php

When building a "Has" type function, I wonder if I should return a boolean like this

```
public function HasGolferAccess($user)
{
    if( $user instanceof GolferInterface)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Is this a good practice?

### EDIT

This will return a strict boolean (1 and 0 are integers, not strict booleans):

```
if( $user instanceof GolferInterface)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest simply doing this:

```
public function HasGolferAccess($user)
{
    return ($user instanceof GolferInterface);
}
```